# raymarching and rasterizing

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to integrate ShaderToy code into a basic OpenGL renderer that only has one plane at y=0, nothing else. However, I do not even know where to start. ShaderToy renders to a uv texture while my plane is rendered real-time in 3D. Are there any examples of how I could integrate or even intermix the two rendering techniques?

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the MVP matrices, and just render as a 2D image.

Suppose this is what you get from shaderToy.

```c
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ) {
    // some code you download from shaderToy
    fragColor = color; // suppose
}
```

Change this to

```c
vec4 mainImage( in vec2 fragCoord ) {
    // some code you download from shaderToy
    return color;
}
```

Vertex shader is trivial, you simply let the OpenGL do the calculation.

```c
#version 330

in vec2 v_vert;
out vec2 f_vert;

void main() {
    f_vert = v_vert;
}
```

Use what you get from the vertex shader to calculate the fragColor, (remember to pass the time varying uniform to the fragment shader), hence the fragment shader should be like the following:

```c
#version 330

uniform float iTime; // this might vary, depends on the version of shaderToy

in vec2 f_vert;
out vec4 FragColor;

vec4 mainImage( in vec2 fragCoord ) {
    // some code you download from shaderToy
    return color;
}

void main() {
    FragColor = mainImage( f_vert );
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. so how does combining raymarched color with rasterized color (from a loaded model) work? can you apply raymarched shadow on a rasterized model, for example?